# Why do I have the following error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMainExecutor(Landroid/content/Context;)

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I tried running my Flutter application on the android emulator, but it won't because of the following error:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             60.6s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing ..\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...             36.2s
W/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(11217): A splash screen was provided to Flutter, but this is deprecated. See flutter.dev/go/android-splash-migration for migration steps.
D/FlutterLocationService(11217): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(11217): Binding to location service.
E/AndroidRuntime(11217): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11217): Process: com.praveeshramroop.athena, PID: 11217
E/AndroidRuntime(11217): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getMainExecutor(Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in class Landroidx/core/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.core.content.ContextCompat' appears in /data/app/com.praveeshramroop.athena-xNhfD9FuVpNs2XnASDlC4w==/base.apk)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterView.onAttachedToWindow(FlutterView.java:506)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:18347)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3397)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3404)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(11217):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

**Other times the errors simply say**:

- Lost connection to device
- Error connecting to service protocol

**pubcpec.yaml file**:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 
  cupertino_icons: null
  firebase_auth: 
  firebase_core: 
  firebase_messaging: 
  flutter_google_places: null
  flutter_spinkit: ^5.1.0
  geocoder: 
  geoflutterfire: 
  geolocator: 
  google_maps_flutter: null
  google_maps_webservice: null
  http: null
  location: ^4.4.0
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^2.0.1
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.1
  provider: null
  rxdart: any
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  uuid: null
  url_launcher: ^6.0.5
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  plugin_platform_interface: 
  geolocator_platform_interface: 
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  google_api_availability:
  google_api_headers: ^1.1.1
  mockito: ^5.2.0
```

**main.dart** page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:txapita/providers/app_state.dart';
import 'package:txapita/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:txapita/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:txapita/screens/splash.dart';
import 'locators/service_locator.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  setupLocator();
  return runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<AppStateProvider>.value(
        value: AppStateProvider(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>.value(
        value: UserProvider.initialize(),
      ),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Txapita',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserProvider auth = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch (auth.status) {
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Splash();
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return LoginScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return MyHomePage();
      default:
        return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

I have no idea what's causing this issue or how to solve it. Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Did you use the Flutter Splash screen package?

Comment: Yes, I did use the Splash screen package.

Comment: Could you include your pubcpec.yaml file

Comment: also include your main.dart page (Your main function)

Comment: I added the pubcpec.yaml file and the main.dart page.

Comment: I would recommend this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash. Please before use make sure to remove any previous splash screen setup. Follow this youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB0dOnc2k10

Comment: Thank you, Georgina, for helping. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue. Is there anything else I can do to solve it?

Comment: Thank you, Georgina, for helping. Unfortunately, that didn't solve the issue. Is there anything else I can do to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will help in Kotlin

```
 val context= LocalContext.current
 ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
```

or

```
 ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
```